# Read file names with underscore in ADF dataflow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a set of .csv files with underscore filename in it. like xxxxxx_cee_nf_BAT_1234561_2020_01_17.csv.gz
xxxxxx_cee_nf_BAT_1234562_2020_01_17.csv.gz

When i try to read these files from ADF DataFlow.. it says cant read the files.
Error thrown in Data Preview is :

**Path does not resolve to any file(s). Please make sure the file/folder exists and is not hidden. At the same time, ensure special character is not included in file/folder name, for example, name start with**

Does anyone come across such errors while reading multiple .csv files where name has underscore.

Thanks in advance.
Ravi Bhat

Comment: I don't believe the underscores are the problem. Can you verify the runtime path resolves properly? Also, if you are reading multiple files, do you mean you are reading a folder of files? If so, that may not be supported with .gz compression.

Comment: Thanks Joel for responding.
Infact I tried giving specific file name in DataSet rather then folder of files. But still it fails with same error message. I read article that.. .GZ is supported file format in dataflow.

Comment: Does your Dataset specify GZ compression?

Comment: Yes, I did set Compression Level - gzip(.gz) at dataset level and wildcard paths : *.csv.gz in Dataflow source option.

Comment: Problem is more of specifying folder of files, if i specify specific file name with compression enabled, it works.

Answer (score 1):

This issue got resolved after doing Import projection. Hack is Import projection will say imported successfully, but you will have wait for 2-3 mins to load the column mappings and then after preview the data.

Comment: I was getting the same error but my issue was that i have deleted file intentionally forgot to run pipeline to recreate the same file. For others, to troubleshoot the issue, do the data preview on every source in the dataflow to find exact source.